# Where to get the NT option pack

Tags: windows

Where do I get the NT option Pack? All the download links I could find are down...
Does somebody know where I can still find it? I have access to MSDNAA, but I couldn't find anything there...

Thanks!
Yvan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any reason you don't move to a newer version of Windows instead? Was this NT 4 or 3.51? It's been a LONG time since anyone referred to the NT Option Pack..

Comment: Unless you are running ISAPI routines the upgrade all the way to IIS 7.5 (Win 2008 R2) shouldn't be too bad - The main differences are security options that the default values changed - Classic ASP hasn't changed all that much over the years if that's what you are using.

I don't know if idc/htx files are still supported, that may be the only true "missing" feature from the oldest IIS.